# Alignment in line

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
        <section class="site-hero site-hero-innerpage overlay" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url(images/big_image_1.jpg);">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center site-hero-inner justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center">

            <div class="mb-5 element-animate">
              <h1>Your Destination. Your Choice.</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class = "row">
        <div class ="col-lg-8">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <div id="map-container" class="embed-responsive-item">
                  <div id="map"></div>
            </div> 
          </div>
       </div>

            <!-- Free Tier -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-4">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Uber</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Plus Tier -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Lyft</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pro Tier -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Parking Garage</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

it aligns as such and im trying to get all the cards to line up.
[Alignment of the Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkrLf.png)

How do I get all my cards to line up on the right and my maps to be on the left?
I am trying to split screen with the maps covering the left side and the cards be on the right

The project is using bootstrap4 and I tried using containers but its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another grid with in the main grid.

Example:

```
<!-- Main Grid -->
<div class="row">

    <!-- Left Box -->
    <div class="col-lg-8">[ Contents Here ]</div>

    <!-- Right Box -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        <!-- Cards Rows -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Card #1 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <!-- Card #2 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <!-- Card #3 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

            <!-- Card #4 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

So your code will be as this: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/YRRgLQ

Hope this is useful.

(You can ignore the CSS here. It's only so the example shows something visible for the map in the "Run code snippet".)

```css
#map,
.embed-responsive-item
{
   background-color: #777;
}

.row>div
{
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="site-hero site-hero-innerpage overlay" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url(images/big_image_1.jpg);">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center site-hero-inner justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
            <div class="mb-5 element-animate">
              <h1>Your Destination. Your Choice.</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class = "row">
        <div class ="col-lg-8">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <div id="map-container" class="embed-responsive-item">
                  <div id="map"></div>
            </div> 
          </div>
       </div>

     <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class = "row">
        
         <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Uber</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Plus Tier -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Lyft</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pro Tier -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Parking Garage</h5>
                  <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="fa-ul">
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
                      <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         
         
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Free Tier -->
            

      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the map by itself `col-8` and the boxes together `col-4`. By setting `col-12 col-md-8` so the map would take 100% by default then 8 cols when over the screen size is medium or larger (up to you).

```css
.map{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <img class="map" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <!-- Free Tier -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Uber</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
        <hr>
        <ul class="fa-ul">
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Plus Tier -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Lyft</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
        <hr>
        <ul class="fa-ul">
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Pro Tier -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Parking Garage</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period"></span></h6>
        <hr>
        <ul class="fa-ul">
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>First Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Second Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Third Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fourth Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Fifthe Option - cost</li>
          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Sixth Option - cost</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
```